# What is the syntax for an argument of type pointer to generic function?

Tags: c++

I have the following generic methods of sorting:

```
template< typename T > void SortMethod_1( T i, T j )
{
...
}

template< typename T > void SortMethod_2( T i, T j )
{
...
}
```

And I would like to implement another test method that receives a pointer to any of the above methods. For example,

```
void TestingSortMethod( argument_1, argument_2, void (* AnyGenericSortMethod)... )
{
...
}
```

How I do it?

How I call it?

Comment: It's called a function *template* in the C++ Standard, which means "a template from which functions can be created (instantiated)". There's no difference between a pointer to a function and a pointer to an instance of a function template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want your test function to be a function template as well:

```
template <typename T>
void TestingSortMethod(
    T argument_1,
    T argument_2,
    void (* AnyGenericSortMethod)(T,T))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by about 3 seconds. Nice.